# How to send a Json to a web service using HttpPost

Tags: java, android, json

Hi I want to send a json object to a web service , I have tried almost everything without success. When the webservice recives the data it returns "eureka" , so I want to be able to see the response too.

```
public void sendData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://pruebaproyectosmi.azurewebsites.net/home/Insert?data=");

    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(json));
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Comment: plz post ur php code?

Comment: is not in php , my code is in ASP.NET/C# but im using http://www.getpostman.com/ to tested  and it seens to be working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void SendBookingData(final String SendCustomerId,final String SendCustomerName, final String BookingDate,
            final String BookingTime, final String SendNetAmount,final String SendTotalAmount, final String SendTotalQuantity,
            final String SendDeliveryDate, final String GetBranchId,final String Senduserid,final String Sendratelistid) {

                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                    try {


                        String SendBookingURL= "your url";
                        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SendBookingURL);       
                        HttpResponse response;
                        json.put("GetcustomerName", SendCustomerName);
                        json.put("GetBookingDate",BookingDate);
                        json.put("GetTotalCost", SendTotalAmount);
                        json.put("GetNetAmount", SendNetAmount);
                        json.put("GetTotalQuantity",SendTotalQuantity );
                        json.put("GetCustomerId", SendCustomerId);
                        json.put("GetDeliveryDate", SendDeliveryDate);
                        json.put("GetBookingtime", BookingTime);
                        json.put("GetBranchId", GetBranchId);
                        json.put("GetUserId", Senduserid);
                        json.put("GetRateListId", Sendratelistid);
                        StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString()); 
                        se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                        post.setEntity(se);
                        try {
                            response = client.execute(post);
                            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                            if(entity != null) {
                                ResponseSummaryTable = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                                System.out.println("body" + ResponseSummaryTable);
                            }
                        }
                          catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                       }
                            catch(Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }       
                       }
```

Comment: shows an error : android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException, How can i fix this issue?

Comment: chnge targetsdk to 9 or put these lines in oncreate  ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);

Answer (score 0):

Send string entity instead

CODE:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpUriRequest request;
request = new HttpPost(<-URL->);
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(<-Your JSON string->);

((HttpPost) request).setEntity(entity);
((HttpPost) request).setHeader("Content-Type",
                    "application/json");

 HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

This code will send json as string entity to server and receives HttpEntity as response

Comment: Hi , i get an error in HttpResponse response = client.execute(request); the error is a null pointer exception

Comment: i dont know what a stacktrace is, i feel really bad

Comment: tell me at which line are you getting a null pointer exception?